# Comparing two POJO classes On two attributes

Tags: java, java-8, pojo

I have two classes

```java
class A {
    String id;
    String name;
    String personalDetails;
}
    
class B {
    String id;
    String name;
    String personalDetails;
}
```

I have to iterate through a list of A and match with id of B and update the details of A with B.

Now why I need to match with both is
I will have a scenario where I have to update only the personal details, may be id is empty but I will have name. so First I have to match with Id if its matched then update details, if match not found then match it with Name then update only details. I just have to extract the details form B. nothing else.

What now I am doing is iterating through list of A,
and I have a `Map bMap = <B.id(key),B(value)>`  (which is not enough as I need to match with Name as well)

```java
if(A.id!=null && bMap.get(A.id)!=null){ 
    A.setPersonalDetails(bMap.get(A.id).getPersonalDetails);
}
```

What I want to achieve is if `A.id` match is not found, then I have to match with `A.name` and `B.name`..
Is there a better way to achieve the same.

Comment: So are you saying that `key` in `bMap = <B.id(key),B(value)>` can be either `B.id` or `B.name`?

Comment: No, Actually that approach wnt work so ineed some better way to do it

Comment: I don't think so.  I'd say code it up just like you said it.  If a match by `id` fails, then try a match on `name`.  I'm curious though.  If you get a match on `name`, do you update the `id` of one object to match the other?  Also, your code above only updates the `personalDetails`.  Will you update the `name` in that case as well?

Comment: @Steve updated the detail in requirement. No I wont update id, name I just need to extract the details from B

Comment: Then perhaps you need 2 maps of `B`s. One with `id` as key and the other with `name` as key.

Comment: Well that would be my end solution the  if no better approaches found. because class B is populated by reading csv usingspark. I just wanted to avoid to read it twice.

Comment: You don't have to read the csv twice. You can populate both maps using the same collection and at the same time.

Comment: for Id I do this .. `getSparkContext().textFile(staticDataPath).map(StaticData::mapStaticDatatRow)
                        .collect().parallelStream().collect(Collectors.toMap(detail -> detail.getid(), detail -> detail,(a, b)->{return a;}));`

Comment: Got it though thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

You would do something like this:

```
Map<String, B> bById = ...
Map<String, B> bByName = ...
for (A a : listA) {
   B b = bById.getOrDefault(a.id, bByName.get(a.name));
   if (b != null) {
      a.setPersonalDetails(b.getPersonalDetails);
   }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

you can use comparator to achieve this.Just a example psudo code is given below

```java
Collections.sort(listA, Comparator.comparing(A::getId)
              .thenComparing(A::getName)
              .thenComparing(A::getAge));
```

Comment: Is it inefficient though to do everything with one match expression if your logic will be different depending on which attribute of the two objects matched?  Is the code easier to follow, and possibly more efficient, if the two comparison are done independently?

Comment: I would complete by extracting the common interface (`C`) between those two classes and write a `Comparator<C>`. Your answer is not clear for the author wants to compare `A` class with `B`.